# Param Cmnd_Alias bypass with script

Tags: linux, sudoers

I tried config de param NOEXEC in sudoers for ban the excution of certains programs, by example;

Cmnd_Alias NOEXEC=!/*/bin/cp *visudo*

But, if create a script with the command cp /usr/sbin/visudo , i created a bypass and run without problems visudo;

#!/bin/sh
cp /usr/sbin/visudo .

How restrict the commands of Cmnd_Alias when they are called from a script?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read `man 5 sudoers`: [Limitations of the `!` operator](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Limitations_of_the_!).